# How to eliminate windows partition

Tags: partitioning, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove Windows Vista Partition So Ubuntu Fills Entire Hard Drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80010/remove-windows-vista-partition-so-ubuntu-fills-entire-hard-drive)

I am preparing to update ubuntu on an old laptop.  Originally windows was hacked and I had an ubuntu image (from school) on cd and launched it with no computer IQ and was back online surfing the web in aprox 10 minutes.  Love at first bite!  But the way I went about it, the windows partition is half my discspace.  Now I want to give Ubuntu the whole territory when I load the new updated image.  will there be a screen asking if I want to partition or allow ubuntu the entire HD?