# Removing Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem

I've been running Precise and XP in a dual-boot on my laptop for several months now.  I'd like to pull the plug on XP and reclaim that wasted NTFS space.  What's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: This doesn't seem significantly different from http://askubuntu.com/questions/80010/remove-windows-vista-partition-so-ubuntu-fills-entire-hard-drive/80011#80011

Answer (score 2):

Removing windows is easy when you have Ubuntu installed.

1. Open the disk utility in Ubuntu
2. Select the partition where Windows is installed and format it.

This is enough to reclaim free space.

Still if you want to remove the Windows entry from grub, follow the [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/grub-customizer-30-released.html).

Answer (score 0):

This should be the right way to do it:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows

I missed that you had dual boot, sorry! :)

Comment: why install a new ubuntu? he just want to reclaim the space. Not reinstallation of ubuntu.

Comment: ah, good! I missed that part as it was dual! Thank you! :)

Comment: I have now edited the Answer to so that it will answer your question correctly!